# Vagrant does not assign correct gateway

Tags: networking, ubuntu-12.04, vagrant

I have created with Vagrant a brand new VM running Ubuntu 12.04 
Since I need to access the VM always at the same IP address I have assigned to it a MAC address and set my DHCP in order to assign the same IP to the machine with that MAC.

My VagrantFile looks like

```
Vagrant::Config.run do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu-vm"
  config.vm.box_url = "http://files.vagrantup.com/precise32.box"
  config.vm.network :bridged, :bridge =>  "BGigabit Ethernet", :mac => "080027234567"
end
```

The VM is correctly created and the same IP assigned every time I boot it up. However, the Gateway is not properly configured.

Here my ifconfig

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:12:96:98
          inet addr:10.0.2.15  Bcast:10.0.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe12:9698/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:436 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:360 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:46526 (46.5 KB)  TX bytes:41271 (41.2 KB)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:23:45:67
          inet addr:142.17.1.10  Bcast:142.17.3.255  Mask:255.255.252.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe12:3456/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:910 errors:0 dropped:6 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:10 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:72559 (72.5 KB)  TX bytes:1604 (1.6 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

and here my routes

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         10.0.2.2        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
default         10.0.2.2        0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
10.0.2.0        *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
142.17.0.0      *               255.255.252.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
```

The eth1 gateway should be 142.17.0.1. Shouldn't the correct address be fetched from the DHCP?

Do I have to specify some extra params in my Vagrantfile to make it work?

THANKS.

Comment: You can only have one default gateway per system (not per interface). Your current gateway is set to 10.0.2.2 (probably the Vagrant master) over eth0 (Vagrant's management interface)

Comment: I see, the first issue is why eth1 has 142.17.0.0 instead 142.17.0.1 that is the gateway in my DHCP?

Moreover, how can I set the last route as default?

Comment: You don't have a gateway set on eth1. 142.17.0.0 is the network address (covers 142.17.0.1 to 142.17.0.254) which is routed directly to eth1 without using a gateway.

Comment: Thanks for you help. So, you mean everything seems fine to you. Correct?

Comment: Yes, it does. can you ping 8.8.8.8?

Comment: From inside the VM I can ping it however I'm not able to ping any other machine in the network ```--- 142.17.1.4 ping statistics ---
24 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 23096ms```